# Is it possible to see source code of a value of function

Tags: r

I am using a function from a package. this function returns some values. For example:

```
k<-dtw(v1,v2, keep.internals=TRUE)
```

and I can get this value:

```
k$costMatrix
```

Does it possible to see the source code of `costMatrix`? if yes how can I do that?

**UPDATE**
this is the source code of the function:

```
   function (x, y = NULL, dist.method = "Euclidean", step.pattern = symmetric2, 
    window.type = "none", keep.internals = FALSE, distance.only = FALSE, 
    open.end = FALSE, open.begin = FALSE, ...) 
{
    lm <- NULL
    if (is.null(y)) {
        if (!is.matrix(x)) 
            stop("Single argument requires a global cost matrix")
        lm <- x
    }
    else if (is.character(dist.method)) {
        x <- as.matrix(x)
        y <- as.matrix(y)
        lm <- proxy::dist(x, y, method = dist.method)
    }
    else if (is.function(dist.method)) {
        stop("Unimplemented")
    }
    else {
        stop("dist.method should be a character method supported by proxy::dist()")
    }
    wfun <- .canonicalizeWindowFunction(window.type)
    dir <- step.pattern
    norm <- attr(dir, "norm")
    if (!is.null(list(...)$partial)) {
        warning("Argument `partial' is obsolete. Use `open.end' instead")
        open.end <- TRUE
    }
    n <- nrow(lm)
    m <- ncol(lm)
    if (open.begin) {
        if (is.na(norm) || norm != "N") {
            stop("Open-begin requires step patterns with 'N' normalization (e.g. asymmetric, or R-J types (c)). See papers in citation().")
        }
        lm <- rbind(0, lm)
        np <- n + 1
        precm <- matrix(NA, nrow = np, ncol = m)
        precm[1, ] <- 0
    }
    else {
        precm <- NULL
        np <- n
    }
    gcm <- globalCostMatrix(lm, step.matrix = dir, window.function = wfun, 
        seed = precm, ...)
    gcm$N <- n
    gcm$M <- m
    gcm$call <- match.call()
    gcm$openEnd <- open.end
    gcm$openBegin <- open.begin
    gcm$windowFunction <- wfun
    lastcol <- gcm$costMatrix[np, ]
    if (is.na(norm)) {
    }
    else if (norm == "N+M") {
        lastcol <- lastcol/(n + (1:m))
    }
    else if (norm == "N") {
        lastcol <- lastcol/n
    }
    else if (norm == "M") {
        lastcol <- lastcol/(1:m)
    }
    gcm$jmin <- m
    if (open.end) {
        if (is.na(norm)) {
            stop("Open-end alignments require normalizable step patterns")
        }
        gcm$jmin <- which.min(lastcol)
    }
    gcm$distance <- gcm$costMatrix[np, gcm$jmin]
    if (is.na(gcm$distance)) {
        stop("No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints")
    }
    if (!is.na(norm)) {
        gcm$normalizedDistance <- lastcol[gcm$jmin]
    }
    else {
        gcm$normalizedDistance <- NA
    }
    if (!distance.only) {
        mapping <- backtrack(gcm)
        gcm <- c(gcm, mapping)
    }
    if (open.begin) {
        gcm$index1 <- gcm$index1[-1] - 1
        gcm$index2 <- gcm$index2[-1]
        lm <- lm[-1, ]
        gcm$costMatrix <- gcm$costMatrix[-1, ]
        gcm$directionMatrix <- gcm$directionMatrix[-1, ]
    }
    if (!keep.internals) {
        gcm$costMatrix <- NULL
        gcm$directionMatrix <- NULL
    }
    else {
        gcm$localCostMatrix <- lm
        if (!is.null(y)) {
            gcm$query <- x
            gcm$reference <- y
        }
    }
    class(gcm) <- "dtw"
    return(gcm)
}
```

but if I write `globalCostMatrix` I dont get the source code of this function

Comment: I think that the '#here some code' will tell you how it is created the data for the globalCostMatrix and then for this 'costMatrix'.  You can't access it directly to the 'globalCostMatrix'because it is encapsulated in the other function definition.

Comment: I have copied the complete code. I cant see the implementation of `globalCostMatrix` in this function

Comment: You can find the function's definition by going to CRAN's site for `dtw` package, download the source tar ball and go to `globalCostMatrix.R` file in `/R` folder. You are not seeing this function in R because it has not been exported in `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thank you, you have answerd my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find how functions work is by looking at the source. You have a good chance that by typing function name in the R console, you will get the function definitions (although not always with good layout, so seeking the source where brackets are present, is a viable option).

In your case, you have a function `dtw` from the same name package. This function uses a function called `globalCostMatrix`. If you type that name into R, you will get an error that object was not found. This happens because the function was not exported when the package was created, probably because the author thinks this is not something a regular user would use (but not see!) or to prevent clashes with other packages who may use the same function name.

However, for an interested reader, there are at least two ways to access the code in this function. One is by going to CRAN, downloading the source tarballs and finding the function in the `R` folder of the tar ball. The other one, easier, is by using `getAnywhere` function. This will give you the definition of the function just like you're used for other, user accessible functions like `dtw`.

```
> library(dtw)
> getAnywhere("globalCostMatrix")
A single object matching ‘globalCostMatrix’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:dtw
with value

function (lm, step.matrix = symmetric1, window.function = noWindow, 
    native = TRUE, seed = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (!is.stepPattern(step.matrix)) 
        stop("step.matrix is no stepMatrix object")
    n <- nrow(lm)
... omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to see what the function `dtw()` does with your data. I seems that it creates a data.frame containing a column named `costMatrix`.

To find out how the data in the column `costMatrix` was generated, just type and execute `dtw` (without brackets!). R will show you the source of the function `dtw()` afterwards.